# Subspace in which the subgroup acts

Tags: finite-groups, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider the unitary group $\mathcal U(n)$ of $n \times n$ unitary matrices, generated by the Lie algebra $\mathfrak u(n)=span(iH_1, … iH_{n^2-1})$, acting on the space $\mathbb C(n)$.

By considering only the smaller group $A = e^{\mathfrak{a}}, \mathfrak{a} = span(iH_1, …, iH_{m^2-1}), m<n$, how can I find a mapping of group element from $\mathcal U(n)$ to $A$ and mapping of states from $\mathbb C(n)$ to its corresponding subspace $\mathbb C(m)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of confusion here. Firstly, $\mathfrak{u}_n$ is not the span of $n$ matrices. It is $n^2 - 1$ dimensional (as a real vector space). Presumably you are then asking about taking a subalgebra isomorphic to $\mathfrak{u}_m$, $m<n$. Especially the way you are saying that, it seems like you are implicitly choosing a subspace $\mathbb{C}^m \leq \mathbb{C}^n$ for this to act on. Since we have an inner product kicking around we can identify an ortho-complement $\mathbb{C}^{n-m}\leq \mathbb{C}^n$ while we are at it so that $\mathbb{C}^m \oplus \mathbb{C}^{n-m} = \mathbb{C}^n$. But then we have a natural map from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^m$ given by (ortho-)projection.

Trying to map from the big Lie group onto this smaller subgroup however is not so friendly. Thinking just on the Lie algebra level, we could take $\mathfrak{u}_n = \mathfrak{u}_m \oplus \mathfrak{u}_m^\perp$ (using the Killing form) and define a projection that way, but this is only a direct sum of vector spaces and so does not define a splitting of $\operatorname{U}(n)$ as a product of groups.

Note this last is a general rule, a subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ may or may not have a natural complement $\mathfrak{m}$ in the Lie algebra (i.e. $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{h} \oplus \mathfrak{m}$ as vector spaces) but $\mathfrak{m}$ will, in general, fail to be a subalgebra (i.e. $[\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m}] \not\subset \mathfrak{m}$) and is even more rarely a direct sum decomposition (which requires $[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{m}] = 0$) so there isn't in general a friendly decomposition in the group that corresponds to this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your accurate response. I have corrected the question. A curiosity: since thinking on the Lie algebra level introduces many caveats, is it possible to approach the problem from a Lie group level? A direct mapping of matrices $n \times n \to m \times m$ and a mapping of $n \to m$-sized vectors?

Comment: My point is that working with the Lie algebra is nicer, not that it introduces caveats. The caveats are from trying to move to the Lie group picture. The problem is that we don't have a well defined idea of projection onto a subgroup unless the group is a direct product (semi-direct products sort of work but the projection doesn't have to be a group homomorphism. Also I have realised that I said the dimension is $n^2 - 1$ but it is just $n^2$ (I was thinking of $\mathfrak{su}_n$)